# Land Surface Temperature in GEE: Creating a Time Series Chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, land-surface-temperature

I have this code below for creating a LST for my region. Then, I created a chart with mean values. But Chart is not showing the values in correct range. Values range is in between 2500 to 4500.

Code Link:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0935bdd3dbbfe7489f13053b96143a32

Image[image])

```
//cloud mask
function maskL8sr(col) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = col.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return col.updateMask(mask);
}

// Visualization parameters
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B4'],
  min: 0,
  max: 4000,
  gamma: [1, 0.9, 1.1]
};

var vizParams2 = {
  bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

// Load the collection
var col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .map(maskL8sr)
  .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(geometry);
  });

print(col, 'collection');
Map.centerObject(geometry);
var image = col.median();
Map.addLayer(image, vizParams2);

var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviParams = { min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green'] };
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(geometry), ndviParams, 'NDVI');

var thermal = image.select('ST_B10').multiply(0.1);
var b10Params = { min: 291.918, max: 302.382, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green'] };
Map.addLayer(thermal.clip(geometry), b10Params, 'Thermal');

var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
}).values().get(0));

var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
}).values().get(0));

var fv = ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min)).pow(2).rename('FV');

var a = ee.Number(0.004);
var b = ee.Number(0.986);
var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');
var imageVisParam3 = { min: 0.9865619146722164, max: 0.989699971371314 };
Map.addLayer(EM.clip(geometry), imageVisParam3, 'EMM');

//LST in Celsius Degree 
function addLST (img) {
  var LST =  img.expression(
  '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
  'Tb': img.select('ST_B10').multiply(0.1),
  'Ep': EM.select('EMM')
  }).rename('LST').select('LST');
  return img.addBands(LST);
  }

var withLST = col.map(addLST);
print('withLST', withLST);

print("chart");

print(
  ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: withLST.select('LST'),
    region: geometry,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 1000,
    xProperty: 'system:time_start'
  }));

// Export LST
var export_Collection = withLST.select(['LST']).toBands();
print("export_Collection map", export_Collection);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: export_Collection,
  description: 'LST_collection',
  scale: 30
});

var export_Image = withLST.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
print("export_Image map", export_Image);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: export_Image,
  description: 'LST',
  scale: 30
});
```

Comment: I think you are missing some steps. There is a github repository code that you can use to calculate LST and show in chart. The code includes all cloud masking operations but the LST output is in Kelvin. I have modified the code here to show in degree celcius: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3cdf6b7e8220fe042ec0a3358eecc15b.